# Intellij - cannot connect existing project to an existing Github repo

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I have an existing Intellij (Ultimate 20,1 beta) project that I want to add to an existing Github repo

Within Intellij I have authenticated my account using the 'Settings/Github' option.  I have setup IntelliJ as an authorized app on Github.

When I try to setup the the Github remote I am getting a 'remote: repository not found' error

Any suggestions?

As a postscript, I deleted my rep from Github and then tried using the Intellij Git/Github/Share feature to create the repo from Github.
This process created the new repo but failed with the following message

```
0:18    Can't finish GitHub sharing process
            Successfully created project 'gd-smart' on GitHub, but initial push failed:
            remote: Repository not found.
            repository 'https://github.com/davoutuk/gd-smart.git/' not found
```

Comment: Do you have "use credential helper" enabled by any chance? 
Do you see "Missing access token" under Preferences | Version Control | GitHub?
2020.1 is not the latest version, could you please update to 2021.1 and see whether the issue persists?

Answer (score 0):

Got this working eventually via

```
Within Intellij I unchecked "use credential helper"  
Closed Intellij
Deleted the ".git" sub directory 
Deleted the 'vcs.xml' file 
Made sure that I had a working Github connection under 'Settings/Github' 
Then re-opened Intellij and selected the VCS for Git
```